# How to bundle a Slides add-on with an existing Docs add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-apps-script-addon

I have an existing Google Docs add-on (with a G Suite Marketplace listing) with thousands of users, and I've made a development version of it for Google Slides that I'm ready to publish. I realized now I can bundle them together (which makes a lot of sense).

However, the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons#bundling_add-ons_together) on how to bundle multiple add-ons seem to imply that neither one exists with a GCP project:

> It is possible to bundle add-ons of different types together. This requires them to share a GCP project and G Suite Marketplace listing, as described above. Choose a standard GCP project to use for the bundled add-ons, and switch each add-on to use that GCP project.

Since I already have the Docs add-on in a [standard GCP project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#standard_cloud_platform_projects) (at least I think I do since it's available in G Suite Marketplace), can I just switch the new Slides add-on to point to it?

My goal is to minimize re-authorization of existing users as much as possible.

Also, would this approach simplify having to get my add-on re-approved? It took 6 months the first time, but that was years ago...

Answer (score 1):

You can link your new Slides add-on to your existing GCP project and resubmit it for approval.

Having your users reauthorize your application will happen only if you are accessing different scopes than the last time they authorized.

In regards to the time taken for approving an add-on, there is [no guarantees on time](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/addon-review#review_duration).